# Tomcat servlet unable to read file

Tags: java, file, tomcat, servlets

I'm making a Java web app, which will run under Tomcat. The code will read a number from a file (on the server), do some processing, and both write the result back to the same file (overwriting the old content, not appending it) and display it in an HTML page for the user.

I am using this singleton (to avoid possible problems with multi-threading) to read and write the file, as well as return the number. The servlet class calls this method.

```
public class Singleton {

private static Singleton instance;
private ObjectOutputStream fileOut;
private ObjectInputStream fileIn;
private File file;
private static final String fileName = "/Users/Timmy/Desktop/IDFile.txt";
private static final int SCALE = 1000000;

public synchronized long getNewID() throws IOException{
    if(file == null){
        file = new File(fileName);
    }
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));   
    fileIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

    long lastId;
    String idString;
    try{
        idString = fileIn.readUTF();
        lastId = Long.parseLong(idString);
    }catch(EOFException e){
        System.out.println("EOF EXCEPTION WHILE READING");
        e.printStackTrace();
        lastId = (long)(Math.random() * SCALE);
    }


    fileIn.close();
    fileIn = null;

    long nextId = lastId + ((long)(Math.random() * SCALE)) + 1;

    fileOut.writeChars(Long.toString(nextId) + "\n");
    fileOut.close();
    fileOut = null;

    return nextId;
}

public static Singleton getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return instance;
}

}
```

And here is the Stack Trace:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1072)
at com.digitalpyrite.assassin.server.Singleton.getNewID(Singleton.java:37)
at com.digitalpyrite.assassin.server.Main.doGet(Main.java:42)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The problem I am having is that every single time the getNewID() method is called, an EOFException is thrown when reading the file. It should only be thrown the first time the program is run, when the file is newly created and empty. I have tried various different methods of reading this file, and all have failed. Scanner throws a NoSuchElementException, Reader returns a null when reading the text, etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block to see more details first.

Comment: You always get EOF because the file is initially empty. The first time your code runs it creates the file (empty) and then attempts to read it.  However your code seems to be written to handle this condition, so your question is unclear.  What are you expecting to happen?  What does the file `IDFile.txt` look like?

Comment: I know that it will give an EOF the first time, when the file is empty, but each subsequent time the program runs, it shouldn't because the file is not empty, but it is still giving the error. The file has this one line: `¨Ìw1549606`

Comment: This string `"/Users/Timmy/Desktop/IDFile.txt"` looks *extremely error-prone*. Are you **sure** that this path is pointing to the correct file?

Comment: You really should add synchronization to the getInstance() method as well.  This isn't what's causing your problem but your singleton is not currently thread-safe without that.

Comment: @blgt Yes, I am sure. It successfully creates the file, and I always double-check my file paths as a first step in troubleshooting. (If it matters, I'm on a Mac, so my files might be set up differently from yours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, out of the comments: This string `"/Users/Timmy/Desktop/IDFile.txt"` looks *extremely error-prone*. It may not the problem in your case, but you still ought to un-hardcode it -- like this it's a potential bug in the making.

---

With regards to the EOF issue: first, `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` interact with the same `File` object. Since you're not using them interleaved, you should move the opening of the `OutputStream` to when you're done with the `InputStream`:

```
...
fileIn.close();
fileIn = null;

fileOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
...
```

---

Second: You're writing using different encodings. You should use `writeUTF()` in order to be able to read with `readUTF()`:

```
    idString = fileIn.readUTF();
...
fileOut.writeUTF(Long.toString(nextId) + "\n");
```

If you choose to do this, however, get rid of the `"\n"` newline, otherwise `Long.parseLong()` will **not** correctly parse the input string. Best would be to just use `.readLong()` and `.writeLong()` (since you're using OIS/OOS anyway); that way you'll avoid dealing with strings at all:

```
        lastId = fileIn.readLong();
...
fileOut.writeLong(nextId);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! As always I feel silly now in hindsight knowing what I did wrong... And about the hardcoded file path: That's only there for testing. I'll get rid of it when I actually use the program "for real."